# Taking post value of HTML slider and assigning a text value based on an integer

Tags: php, forms, post

Here is my PHP:

```
$priority = htmlspecialchars($_POST['priority']);
    if ($priority <= 33){
      $priority = 'Low'
  }

  if ($priority <= 66) && ($priority > 33) {
      $priority = 'Medium'
  }

  if ($priority <= 100) && ($priority > 66) {
      $priority = 'High'
  }
```

My code is pretty self explanitory, I'm sending myself an email and I have a slider bar for the user to indicate the priority of their message. The slider POSTS an integer out of 100. This code makes my files break, I appreciate any help that comes my way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a semi-colon at the end of each assignment line.

You can also significantly simplify your code:

```
if ($priority <= 33){
    $priority = 'Low';
} elseif ($priority <= 66) {
   $priority = 'Medium';
} elseif ($priority <= 100) {
    $priority = 'High';
}
```